# Insertar Fecha y tiempo a DATETIME

Tags: java, sql

Tengo una fecha y hora con el siguiente valor: 2017-01-27_12-52-00-9370
Lo que necesito es insertarla a la base de datos con el tipo de dato DATETIME
Gracias.

Comment: Deberías poner el código que tienes hecho diciendo dónde tienes el problema para poder ayudarte. De lo contrario las respuestas pueden ser tan genéricas como cualquier búsqueda rápida en google. Esa no es la política del sitio, sino hacer una pregunta clara con [un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Usa `java.sql.Timestamp` para poder guardar la fecha con más precisión:

```
java.util.Date date = new Date(); //Tu fecha a guardar
tuPreparedStatement.setTimestamp(columIndex, new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime()));
```